# Is this kufr please give me an answer

Tags: hadith, sunnah, kufr

Assalamu alaikum my question is today I told a lie to my mother regarding my exam mark at that time I told the lie I was having a thought in my mind that prophet Muhammad ( let peace be upon him). Had said not to tell lies during that time I didn't paid attention to the thought , is this kufr I don't intend to do kufr or reject Hadith or show any disbelief. Please answer as soon as possible , I am very much terrified

Answer (score 1):

first of all, let me clarify that telling a lie is not Kufr. In shar’i terminology **Kufr** simply **means not believing in Allah or His Messengers**, whether that is accompanied by denial or it is not accompanied by denial but rather doubt, or turning away from faith out of arrogance or because one is following desires that prevent one from following the message.

> “then when there came to them that which they had recognized, they
> disbelieved in it”  [al-Baqarah 2:89](https://quran.com/2/89?translations=85,20,19,17,18,21,84,101)

I am just telling you a little about Kufr so that you may first understand what actually kufr is. The act you committed is surely a sin but is not considered as kufr for sure.
I would suggest you to ask forgiveness for your sin and try to repent.

Thank you.